# redirecting to other methods when calling non-existing methods

Tags: php, class, methods

If I call `$object->showSomething()` and the `showSomething` method doesn't exist I get a fata error. That's OK.

But I have a `show()` method that takes a argument. Can I somehow tell PHP to call `show('Something');` when it encounters `$object->showSomething()` ?

Comment: The workaround is to catch such function calls via `__call` and redirect to the alternative function. If `show*` is your only special case then that's even ok; if you need to split other methods/parameters on camelCase then that's less stellar (would violate language semantics because PHP identifiers are actually case-insensitive).

Comment: I see. __call() only runs when a method is not found?

Comment: Yes, it works as fallback. Real methods have precedence. If anything is not found, `__call` will handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
class Foo {

    public function show($stuff, $extra = '') {
        echo $stuff, $extra;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (preg_match('/^show(.+)$/i', $method, $matches)) {
            list(, $stuff) = $matches;
            array_unshift($args, $stuff);
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'show'), $args);   
        }
        else {
            trigger_error('Unknown function '.__CLASS__.':'.$method, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

$test = new Foo;
$test->showStuff();
$test->showMoreStuff(' and me too');
$test->showEvenMoreStuff();
$test->thisDoesNothing();
```

**Output**:

`StuffMoreStuff and me tooEvenMoreStuff`

Comment: Might want to close the `__call` function of with an `} else { trigger_error('Unknown function '.__CLASS__.':'.$method, E_USER_ERROR); } ` , or it could result in a very difficult to debug class later...

Comment: @Wrikken You're right, I was a bit lazy there. ;)  ... updated the example code.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily just the `show....` methods, but any method, yes, use [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods). Check for the method asked in the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php). Example:

```
class X {
    public function bar(){
        echo "OK";
    }
}
$x = new X();
if(method_exists($x, 'bar'))
    echo 'call bar()';
else
    echo 'call other func';
```