# how this is possible - non-existent method successfully called in php [where is the method from???]

Tags: php, methods, kohana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirecting to other methods when calling non-existing methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268613/redirecting-to-other-methods-when-calling-non-existing-methods)

I have a code, which i'm inspecting and got fantastic feature.

php 5.4.0/Kohana 3.0.3

exactly that strings have troubles:

```
$ticket = ORM::factory('ticket');
$this->template->errors = $ticket->validate()->errors('validate_ticket');
```

the problem is that class Model_Ticket and all of its parents does not contain method validate(), but this method returns valid value.
how can this be possible?

next code shows that:

```
echo 'get_class($ticket)='; echo get_class($ticket); echo "\n";

echo "var_dump(method_exists(\$ticket,'validate'))="; var_dump(method_exists($ticket,'validate')); echo '\n';

echo "var_dump(method_exists('Model_Ticket','validate'))=";var_dump(method_exists('Model_Ticket','validate'));echo '\n'

echo 'get_class($ticket->validate())=';echo get_class($ticket->validate());
```

here what we got as result:

```
get_class($ticket)=Model_Ticket
var_dump(method_exists($ticket,'validate'))=bool(false)
var_dump(method_exists('Model_Ticket','validate'))=bool(false)
get_class($ticket->validate())=Validate
```

get_class_methods($ticket) also shows, that $ticket does not contain method validate()...

Comment: Did you check if it implements [`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) maybe?

Comment: sorry, you was right. one of the parents does that. huge thanks, mario!

Answer (score 0):

`Model` class parent classes don't have `validate()` method.

Due to [Kohana DOCS](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/ORM#__call) when we try to call `validate` method (`elseif ($method === 'validate')`) protected `_validate` method is called.